# Header paths mismatch when migrating to MSYS2/MinGW64

Tags: c++, c, mingw-w64, msys2

I am porting my c/cpp project from gcc/Linux to Windows using MSYS2/MinGW64 environment. Two of the headers were not found where expected and I had to modify include in the way bellow in order to achieve succesful compilation.

```
#ifdef __MINGW64__
#include <ncurses/ncurses.h>
#else
#include <ncurses.h> 
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef __MINGW64__
#include <json/json.h>
#else
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>
#endif
```

However I feel this solution is not correct (or is it?). I think I probably missed something obvious, may be some configuration step. What can I do better?

BTW: I use simple make file which calls g++ with the same set of parameters in Linux and Windows and I do not specify any paths there.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For jsoncpp, you can run this command on both Linux and MSYS2 to get the recommended compiler flags:

```
pkg-config --cflags jsoncpp
```

If you pass those flags to the compiler, then I think a simple `#include <ncurses.h>` should work on both platforms.

That does not work for ncurses, unfortunately, because there is no configuration file for ncurses `/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig/` in MSYS2.

Comment: If I get it correctly it would mean then that the issue with various include paths must be solved in a make file. Then I guess I will have to learn more about makefiles. Thank you for your help.